# How do etherpad & Google Docs do ChangeSets

Tags: javascript, google-docs, etherpad

I'm curious to learn how Etherpad and Google Docs automatically save data. When you're writing a text document the products send only the changes to the server. Any idea how this technology works and where I can go to learn more about the end-2-end?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Etherpad and Google Wave use [Operational Transforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_transformation). Here's an [article about their use in Google Wave](http://www.waveprotocol.org/whitepapers/operational-transform).

Answer (score 2):

John McLear here from the Etherpad foundation.

[Here is a document discussing Etherpad handles changesets](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/raw/master/doc/easysync/easysync-full-description.pdf).